# Once I complete Saints Row: The Third campaign, can I choose the other option for Three Way and still keep my items from the first time playing it?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I chose to save Shaundi and then beat Gangstas In Space. If I go back to do the alternate ending and kill Killbane, Do I still have my items I got from saving Shaundi, Viola, and The Mayor? I don't want to lose Shaundi, Viola, or The Mayor by killing Killbane after beating the game.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
You keep all rewards from beating the last mission the first time even if you replay it. In fact, you actually need to replay the final mission again to 100% the game. After the mission your rewards will not be revoked, you'll still have all your homies and favours and what not.